# Oracle SQL - selective filtering causes cartesian

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, cartesian-product

Oracle 12.2

I have a SQL statement that is causing me issues.  I am retrieving data from a table called BURNDOWN.  If the user is an admin, they get to see all the data.  If the user is NOT an admin, they are restricted to what they can see, based on some join conditions.
The issue I am running into is when the user is an ADMIN, I don’t need the other tables… subsequently, the JOIN condition is not relevant, so Oracle is deciding to do a cartesian join across everything…
How do I get around this so that is the user is an Admin, I only look at one table, else I look at all tables and include the join condition?

The example SQL is a contrived example, but it shows the issue.

```
Select 
BURNDOWN.NAME,
BURNDOWN.ADDRESS,
BURNDOWN.STATE
from BURNDOWN, FILTER_A, FILTER_B, FILTER_C
Where
(
  :ISAdmin = 1
  Or
  (
 BURNDOWN.x=FILTER_A.x and
FILTER_A.y=FILTER_B.y and
FILTER_B.z=FILTER_C.z and
FILTER_C.user = :ThisUser
 )
)
```

Comment: Hint:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `EXISTS` to see if the data exists in the `FILTER` tables without joining them in to the results.

```
select bd.*
from   burndown bd
where  ( :isadmin = 1 or
         exists ( select 1 
                  from   filter_a a
                  inner join  filter_b b on b.y = a.y
                  inner join  filter_c c on c.z = b.z
                  where  a.x = bd.x
                  and    c.user = :ThisUser )
       )
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work? I don't know if Oracle implements any "short cut" boolean logic.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want:

```
select bd.*
from burndown bd
where :ISAdmin = 1 or
      (exists (select 1 from FILTER_A a where bd.x = a.x) or
       exists (select 1 from FILTER_B b where bd.y = b.y) or
       exists (select 1 from FILTER_C c where bd.z = c.z)
      );
```